# Media queries not working on firefox

Tags: css, firefox, media-queries

I have been working with this new technology for me (Responsive Design) and I hate the problems which I don't know the answer, I get frustrated :/

Here is my code: http://jsbin.com/ejadej/1

With the latest version of Chrome, I see the site how is supposed to be by my code, whilst Firefox isn't reading this media query

```
@media screen and(min-width: 960px) {
    #php-info-title {
        background-color: #322E2C;
        position: absolute;
        left:100px;
        bottom: 0px;
        color:white;
        z-index: 0;
        max-width: 300px;
    }
}
```

It's just ignoring it (if I remove the media query it works well, but i don't want to do that).

The curious thing is that with the other media queries written above that one, Firefox works well.

What's going on with Firefox?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7):

Per spec, you need a space between the `and` and the `(`.  If you don't have it, it's not a valid `@media` rule.

I filed https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=117396 and http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=248043 for what it's worth.

Comment: Jajaj that's right man! thanks .. what a stupid problem. I'm not used to pay attention to those little details, but apparently firefox does.

Comment: Thanks @boris ... i too had this same issue in fire-fox, Though my code had none of that space issue. But as i included my minified css to my index.html i had to face this.. its fixed now :)